# How to add existing code to a story board skeleton UI?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have made a tabbed application using the storyboard, and each tab has its own view controller. Currently, each tab does nothing but display an image, but I need to add some existing code to each view controller that some partners have coded up. I'm very new to xcode and swift, and am wondering how to do this. These were coded without using the storyboard, but mine was exclusively using the story board. Would I just need to copy the viewcontroller.swift onto each one that I have in my skeleton UI?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> Would I just need to copy the viewcontroller.swift onto each one that I have in my skeleton UI?

Not *just* copy it. There are two stages. To illustrate, let’s say that we’re going to have the code for one of your tabs in a view controller called MyViewController1. Then:

1. You need to declare `class MyViewController1`. This is usually done in a file *MyViewController1.swift* (though no law requires that).
2. You need to tell the storyboard that this view controller *is* a MyViewController1 (and not merely a plain vanilla UIViewController). You do that in the scene’s view controller’s Identity inspector.